# How to restore a scarp surface grid to calculate material loss

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, grass-7.0, volume, gmt

I would like to calculate the volume of material lost from a scarp like the one shown in the following image:

[image]

Is there a way to do these calculations with open-source software such as GMT, QGIS and GRASS?

Comment: Erase contours inside them and triangulate what remains. Difference of DEMs will give you very rough idea of    individual volumes.

Comment: thanks, a first idea is to mask the scarp area and then triangulate that area, right?

Comment: GRASS GIS offers a volume calculator in https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.volume.html

Comment: Do you have a before and after raster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will try to address your question with **GRASS**.

Your problem has a first task that is a bit challenging already, which is to get the situation before the event you want to quantify. I think the best option is to produce a raster of the original situation. To produce it, I would use some countour lines to draw "by hand" the terrain as it was before the event, then with the help of `r.surf.contour` fill a terrain model.

Once you have the two rasters, before and after, you ca produce a raster of the difference with `r.mapcalc` (rasterDiff= rasterBefore - rasterAfter). I guess you will need appropiate masks to box your areas of interest.

You can have the volume by using the `r.sum` of rasterDiff and multiplying the results by the cell size.

### UPDATE

@Gery provided a working example offshore Nicaragua and I attempted to calculate the volume with my own description above using GRASS and  bit QGIS.

```
 |        Projection: Latitude-Longitude                                  
 |
 |            N: 11:15:44.273502N    S: 10:55:46.447629N   Res: 0:00:02.76634 |
 |            E: 87:04:08.435069W    W: 87:23:22.390832W   Res: 0:00:02.80086 |
 |   Range of data:    min = -4783.09  max = -760.2788                        |`
```

[image: Here an overview of the scarp around 3000 m below sea level]

1. Load the DTM and set the region to the input data

   `r.import input=mb.grd output=mb
   g.region raster=mb`
2. Digitalize the contourlines before the slide. I did the digitalization in QGIS and I saved the elevation values in field  `level`

   `v.import input=Contour50_WGS84.shp layer=Contour50_WGS84 output=Contour50_WGS84`

[image: Contour lines before the slide]

3. Digitalize the boundaries of the scarp to use it as a mask.

   `v.import input=mascara.shp layer=mascara output=mascara`

[image: Mask]

4. Mask the area of interest and fill the null values

   `r.mask --overwrite vector=mascara
     r.fillnulls input=mb output=mbfilled method=rst`
5. Conversion of contour lines into raster lines and interpolation for the DTM prior the slide

   `v.to.rast input=Contour50_WGS84 type=line output=prescarp use=attr attribute_column=level
    r.surf.contour input=prescarp output=prescarpfilled`

[image]

6. Calculate the difference between the two rasters

   `r.mapcalc expression=scarpdepth = prescarpfilled   - mbfilled`

[image]

7. Calculate the average cell size and the sum of the `scarpdepth`

   `r.report map=MASK units=me
   |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
   |                     Category Information                      |       square|
   |#|description                                                  |       meters|
   |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
   |1|Value 1. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |   53,830,997|
   |*|no data. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |1,235,078,890|
   |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
   |TOTAL                                                          |1,288,909,887|
   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+`

   `r.univar map=scarpdepth
   total null and non-null cells: 178396
   total null cells: 170947
   Of the non-null cells:
   ----------------------`
   `n: 7449
   minimum: -2.60534
   maximum: 387.981
   range: 390.586
   mean: 206.303
   mean of absolute values: 206.305
   standard deviation: 76.9735
   variance: 5924.92
   variation coefficient: 37.3109 %
   sum: 1536751.12633864`

Then, with 7449 cells and an area of 53.8 km^2, the cell size is 7226 m^2/cell

8. The volume is +/-11 km^3 approximately (7,226 m^2 * 1,536,751 m)

Comment: thanks for your answer, would you show a minimal working example please?

Comment: @Gery, it is going to take a while to give it the required time, but it is still fun. Do you have a *nice scarp* to share?

Comment: I think I have one, where can I upload it for you?

Comment: I think pasetbin is a good place to share a working example. I have just pasted a small clip from the srtm_22_20.tif as a plain ascii file here https://pastebin.com/tzYPBDSE. Any public place, if it is not already public data, would be fine

Comment: sorry it took me a while to share the grid with the nice scarp, please find it here: https://ufile.io/3i2ix

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to read your file, the `mb.grd`, in Qgis or GRASS

Comment: @gery it seems to be bathymetry, but I do not know how to read it without getting just zeros. I posted a question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260474/how-to-read-netcdf-raster-data-in-grass-or-qgis

Comment: `mb.grd` is NETCDF, you can read it in GRASS afaik, which format would be better for you?

Comment: Eres un genio mi amigo! great job my friend, nice MWE.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to calculate the volume of ore that has been excavated in an open-pit mine, using QGIS and GRASS. I used the same method suggested here except for the step 7.

To calculate the volume of a raster, maybe you could use r.volume in GRASS. It does the same thing as explained here, but there are no intermediate results which are rounded up, so I think it is more precise!

I used the two methods to compare the results. I found that there could be tens of meters of difference up to ten-thousands of meters of difference, depending on how you round your results. So maybe it is worth using r.volume instead.

Hope that helps!