# Calculating volume of areas from CHM

Tags: qgis, polygon, dem, volume

I classified laying logs (tree trunks) from CHM (Canopy Height Model = Digital Surface Model (DSM) - Digital Terrain Model (DTM)) created from LiDAR point cloud. I converted classified logs into polygon shapefile. I now have polygons that represent logs and CHM image. CHM were clipped by polygons (logs), now I am thinking of calculating volume of each log using QGIS. Is there any existing method?

Comment: Suggestion 1: Share with us the software you're working with.

Comment: Thanks @Erik, I updated my question. I have access to QGIS and ArcGIS software

Comment: Then please choose one you're more apt at working with, maybe do some research on the general workflow and edit your question accordingly, thank you.

Comment: Thank you @Andre Silva. And I am sorry for not providing enough details. I updated the question, hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Thanks for editing. You will find the answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265489/how-to-measure-volume-in-raster. Run the Zonal Statistics tool. Multiply the mean height by the polygon area.