# Calculating Volume differences between two DTM from different years with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, volume

I need to calculate the volume of the differences between two DTM from different years with QGIS.  I am trying to figure out how to do it, but I do not see anything clear about that.

Could anyone give me a tip to be able to do it?

Comment: what approach did you try out and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Looking for information on internet I saw that there is a tool in SAGA, raster volume, but for some reason I do not have it.  In ArcGIS there is one, cut/Fill, but I have to do it by using QGIS.  I think that the best way will be to do it by hand, which means to rest my two raster and to add the histogram as the resolution of my raster is 1 meter.

Comment: See my answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258482/how-to-restore-a-scarp-surface-grid-to-calculate-material-loss/259451#259451. You can start from step 6

Comment: its not getting correct volume

Answer (score 3):

The usage of SAGA `raster volume` is slightly different from what you would expect with ArcGIS `Cut/Fill`, as it is a tool to calculate a volume above a reference surface.

How about simply using QGIS `Raster Calculator`?

(1) Subtract `raster_b` from `raster_a`

[image]

[image]

(2) You will obtain output raster.

[image]

(3) If it was ArcGIS `Cut Fill` tool, it will immediately give you `Cut volume` and `Fill volume` summarized in a table. With QGIS, you would probably use `Raster layer statistics` tool (in QGIS geoalgorithm | Raster tools) or other plugins, which fits for your target statistics.