# Calculating volumes

Tags: dem, volume

I am using QGIS 3.22.1 for this task.

I have points with X, Y, Z of river bed. I have two sets, first is top of the mud and second is bottom of the mud-gravel layer. My goal is to calculate difference between these two DEMs. My process was this:

1. Made two DEMs from points
2. Raster to vector both
3. Intersection of these polygons
4. Then mask layer (I have points in C shape, so I needed to remove excess areas)
5. Clip both DEM with mask layer
6. Raster calculator (top DEM - bottom DEM)
7. Raster zonal statistics
8. In attribute table of statistics - calculate new column "Volume" = ("m2"*"sum")
9. Basic statistics for fields - "Volume"

After this procedure I have an HTML file with "sum" which shows number "67366.96377954601". This is not possible. Area of DEM is 7600 m2. This means that there is 8,85 m of mud. This is not true. Difference DEM shows values from -0,19 m to 2,74 m.

Do you have any suggestions? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which software are you working with?

Comment: Thank you for reply, I am using QGIS 3.22.1.

Comment: You can check out this answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277572/volume-of-a-raster?rq=1

Comment: QGIS allows you to calculate volumes directly from raster DEM, no need to convert stuff (check the link Padmanabha posted).

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. Now i have valid volume of 5549 m3.