# Comparing DEM volume using GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, dem, volume

I have two DEMs of an open-pit mine taken a few weeks apart. I would like to estimate the volume that has been excavated during that interval, ie the difference of volume between the two DEMs.

Can I do that with GRASS? If so how?

If not, do you have any suggestion on how to do it? (I would prefer using an open source software...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference of two rasters, before and after, can be  produced as a new raster with `r.mapcalc` (rasterDiff= rasterBefore - rasterAfter).

Then, you can have the volume by using the `r.report` of rasterDiff and multiplying the results by the cell size.

You can go to step 6 of this Q&A [How to restore a scarp surface grid to calculate material loss](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258482/how-to-restore-a-scarp-surface-grid-to-calculate-material-loss/259451#259451)